# Can a app that uses location service in iOS be auto started at boot time

Tags: ios, gps, autostart

While I have read in the **apple's documentation** that **VoIP** based apps will be **auto started** after a boot, there is no mention of apps that use **GPS**. This should mean that **apps that are registered for GSP will not be auto started** when device boots.

However I ***need*** to make sure that my understanding is correct before I move ahead.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of "auto start" in iOS neither the concept of "boot time" from the point of view of 3rd party apps. When the OS starts all applications that were open before the shutdown will be "opened" again and put in inactive state. VoIP and GPS applications can request something like 10s CPU in every 10 mins. These cycles will be restarted automatically after device boot if the application was running before shutdown. However this is not "autostart" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot launch your application by using background service like voip.
You can activate this service by enabling it on info.plist file.